# Creating Web Worker in React Native Android app

Tags: react-native

I am building a React Native android app. In app I want to download and parse huge amount of data from server. Since JavaScript is a single threaded language I don't want to execute this on same React Native JSC context. Is it possible to create a Web Worker inside React Native JSC context and do extensive background jobs?

I have tried to do the same, but it says function not available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a library exactly for that now. Check out https://github.com/devfd/react-native-workers

Comment: appreciate the effort you have put into this project. do you have any plan for windows platform too?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's not my project, I just found it :) but looking at the issues, it doesn't seem to bein the plans... are you building for Windows phone?

Comment: Unfortunately that project seems to be unmaintained. 

As a warning to those who come across this. It no longer works for RN 40+ https://github.com/devfd/react-native-workers/issues/25

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK there is no WebWorker polyfill for React Native. You will probably have to write a Native Bridge Module. If you want to avoid that , check out this  post where they use requestAnimationFrame to break heavy tasks. https://corbt.com/posts/2015/12/22/breaking-up-heavy-processing-in-react-native.html

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion. Is there tutorial using that we can easily write the Native Bridge Module using React Native JSC Concept.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays a library that tries to do something similar with JSI but that is not declared exactly as WebWorker is [react-native-multithreading](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-multithreading).

For now there is no solution within react-native but news may come in https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/486

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).